# SOAPpy equivalent library for Red Hat Enterprise Linux(RHEL) 8 in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rhel, soappy

From the [link](https://%20%3Chttps://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_8/changes-to-packages_considerations-in-adopting-rhel-8%3E) we could see that, SOAPpy is being removed from the RHEL8 image. I would like to run python based application on RHEL8 which uses following methods.

```
SOAPpy.buildSOAP
SOAPpy.parseSOAPRPC
```

So far I tried installing `SOAPpy-py3` as it seems that package for python3. However I get the following error while installing.

[image]

Due to some reason(may be not supported), installation is getting failed. My question is.

1. Is there a way to install `SOAPpy-py3` on RHEL8(like some rpm package or something like that)?
2. What are other alternatives which can provide me these listed functionality?